# Google Signin Error

Tags: google-api-php-client

I downloaded the Google API PHP client https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and tried using it with Google Sign-in. However, the instructions everywhere are very unclear. When I try doing `require_once __DIR__ . '/Google/autoload.php'`, I get the error

> [Sun Feb 18 04:02:58.847259 2018] [:error] [pid 975] [client
>   ::1:48964] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: This library must be
>   installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the
>   instructions at
>   https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation. in
>   /var/www/html/auth/Google/autoload.php:14\nStack trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/auth/index.php(6): require_once()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown
>   in /var/www/html/auth/Google/autoload.php on line 14

Now, after looking at the code, on line 9 of autoload.php it reads:

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Now, I was never told anywhere about there being a 'vendor' directory, I don't know what the Google developers expected. Why does it expect there to be a 'vendor' directory? What's supposed to be in the 'vendor' directory?

Comment: Would it be better to rename this to 'Google API PHP Client Error'? It's not really specific to Google Sign in.

Comment: You have to install composer on your host. Please refer to the readme file, as all is explained in there. If you still don't want to use composer, download the entire release (see releases tab on github), but it may not be up to date